# passing data structures from java to perl

Tags: java, perl, parsing

I would like to pass some data structures from java to perl.

In perl, this should basically be a hash where the keys are strings and each value is either a string, a hash or a hash of hashes.

Is there a way to dump data from java that can be easily parsed by perl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSON and YAML are serialization standards that have both Java and Perl implementations.